# Could not find an overload for 'println' that accepts the supplied arguments

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking, swift

I'm porting my Objective-C code to Swift and got stuck with a weird error. I'm using a bridged version of https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFOAuth1Client if it helps.

Can you please point me what's wrong? Thank you.

A working Objective-C code:

```
[oauthClient authorizeUsingOAuthWithRequestTokenPath:@"oauth_request.php"
    userAuthorizationPath:@"oauth_authorize.php"
    callbackURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"oob"]
    accessTokenPath:@"oauth_access.php"
    accessMethod:@"POST"
    scope:nil
    success:^(AFOAuth1Token *accessToken, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Success: %@", accessToken);
    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
}
```

A reference method prototype in Objective-C:

```
- (void)authorizeUsingOAuthWithRequestTokenPath:(NSString *)requestTokenPath
                          userAuthorizationPath:(NSString *)userAuthorizationPath
                                    callbackURL:(NSURL *)callbackURL
                                accessTokenPath:(NSString *)accessTokenPath
                                   accessMethod:(NSString *)accessMethod
                                          scope:(NSString *)scope
                                        success:(void (^)(AFOAuth1Token *accessToken, id responseObject))success
                                        failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure;
```

A template with Swift code:

```
oauthClient.authorizeUsingOAuthWithRequestTokenPath(
    requestTokenPath: String?,
    userAuthorizationPath: <#String?#>,
    callbackURL: <#NSURL?#>,
    accessTokenPath: <#String?#>,
    accessMethod: <#String?#>,
    scope: <#String?#>,
    success: ((AFOAuth1Token!, AnyObject!) -> Void)?,
    failure: ((NSError!) -> Void)?
)
```

A broken Swift code:

```
oauthClient.authorizeUsingOAuthWithRequestTokenPath(
    requestTokenPath: "oauth_request.php",
    userAuthorizationPath: "oauth_authorize.php",
    callbackURL: "oob",
    accessTokenPath: "oauth_access.php",
    accessMethod: "POST",
    scope: nil,
    success: { (accessToken: AFOAuth1Token!, responseObject: AnyObject!) in
        println("Success")
    },
    failure: { (error: NSError!) in
        println("Failure")
    }
)
```

Comment: Could you point us at the line that the error's on? I know there's only two `println`s in what you've posted, but it seems so unlikely that `println("Success")` or `println("Failure")` is causing an error that it might be best to highlight it...

Comment: Matt, the highlighted line is "oauthClient.authorizeUsingOAuthWithRequestTokenPath(", see http://cl.ly/image/052u1L1S2e0t

Comment: The only obvious thing I can see that's wrong with that line is that you're passing in a string for the NSURL parameter. I'm wondering if the (beta) compiler is getting confused and putting out a duff error message for the error that should be telling you that. Can you pass in an NSURL for callbackURL instead of the string literal you've got there? (There's an NSURL `init` for Swift that takes a string, so it should be as easy as `NSURL("oob")`)

Comment: Oh, and you probably don't want the first parameter named. In Swift, the first parameter to a method doesn't need the parameter to be named (to avoid the redundancy you can see there with `authorizeUsingOAuthWithRequestTokenPath(requestTokenPath:...`). So try leaving the `requestTokenPath:` parameter name out of the method call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Matt Gibson suggested:

```
oauthClient.authorizeUsingOAuthWithRequestTokenPath(
    "oauth_request.php",
    userAuthorizationPath: "oauth_authorize.php",
    callbackURL: NSURL(string: "oob"),
    accessTokenPath: "oauth_access.php",
    accessMethod: "POST",
    scope: nil,
    success: { (accessToken: AFOAuth1Token!, responseObject: AnyObject!) in
        println("Success")
    },
    failure: { (error: NSError!) in
        println("Failure")
    }

)
```

Works like a charm! Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can also let type inference make the closure declarations shorter: all you need is `success: { accessToken, responseObject in` and `failure { error in`, because the compiler already knows the parameter types.