# Swift, return value from asynchronous block

Tags: ios, asynchronous, swift

Very new to iOS development and I've just started dabbling in GCD, I've read several articles on SO and have consulted Apple's documentation, however I am struggling to understand how to set a return value from an "expensive" operation.

The below function will loop over sum 100K users (as an example), doing this on the main thread would obviously halt the GUI for several seconds, therefore in my UserList class, I propose to execute this block asynchronously on my its thread:

```
let queue = dispatch_queue_create("me.alexsims.user_queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT)

public func getUserById(userId: String, completionHandler: (result: User) -> ())
{
    dispatch_async(queue)
    {
        for user in self.users {
            if user.getUserId() == userId
            {
                completionHandler(result: user)
            }
        }
        // Return an empty user object
        completionHandler(result: User())
    }
}
```

Now from my understanding, the `result` variable should be returned and I should then be able to access the `User()` object which is stored in there from my main thread

However, when I return to my controller and run a test:

```
var list   = UserList()
var a_user = User()

a_user = list.getUserByID(userId: "xyz", completionHandler: { (result) -> () in
    println(result)
})
```

this throws the error `Could not find an overload for 'println' that accepts the supplied arguments`, I'm guessing thats because I am not on the main queue? So I try:

```
a_user = list.getUserById(userId: "xyz", completionHandler: { (result) -> () in
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        println(result)
    }
})
```

However, I still get the same error. What am I doing wrong here?

**SOLVED**
As Daniel spotted, the problem was providing the optional parameter to the `list.getUserByID` call.
After changing it to:

```
a_user = list.getUserById("abcde", completionHandler: { (result) -> () in
    println(result)
})
```

The println error vanished.

Comment: thats not a threading issue, the system can't print out your custom object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Swift class `User` needs to implement the Printable protocol so that it can be used by println.

Something like this:

```
Class User: Printable {
  let name = "Bob"
  var description: String {
    return "User: \(name)"
  }
}
```

Read more in this [Apple post](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Printable.html)

If you are feeling lazy, make your User class a subclass of NSObject which already implements the Printable protocol

### Edit

A quick search of your println error turned [this up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24223970/could-not-find-an-overload-for-println-that-accepts-the-supplied-arguments). Not sure why the error falls through to println but heres a fix:

Try removing the first parameter of your function call, in Swift you don't need to type the first parameter to avoid redundancy:

`a_user = list.getUserById(userId: "xyz...`

Should be:

`a_user = list.getUserById("xyz...`

Comment: Which part exactly? Your issue has nothing to do with what thread you are on:) will update my post to be more clear

Comment: The only problem is, my User class inherits from a Person class, I tried setting "Printable" on my Person class to fix this, but I still get the `could not find overload for println that accepts the supplied arguments` error

Comment: @Alex check my answer again

Comment: Jheeze, removing `userId` fixed the problem, how strange...thanks for your help Daniel :)

Comment: @Alex anytime man, crazy odd error. Perhaps update your question to include the error? So weird. But all the best with iOS man:)

Comment: will update my question now, hopefully it helps someone else in the future - cheers man, all the best to you!