# How does a callback/closure know to wait after Asynchronous call is finished?

Tags: swift, networking, callback, closures

I am new to Swift and have a question concerning callbacks/closures. During a Asynchronous network call different items come at different times. I would like to know how a callback knows not to get executed until everything we are looking for from the request in returned?

EDIT:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { 
    //Array to store HingeImage objects
    var myImageArray = Array<HingeImage>()

    for items in parsedResult {

        //Create custom objects with values needed
        let finalObjects = HingeImage(dictionary: items as! [String : AnyObject])

        myImageArray.append(finalObjects)

    }

    // Callback completion
    callback(hingeImages: hingeImageArray, error: nil)
})
```

EDIT 2 :

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        callTheCallBackAndGrabData()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func callTheCallBackAndGrabData() {

        MainVC.requestWithCallback { (hingeImage, error) in
            print(hingeImage)

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It reads the programmer's mind and does the "Right Thing"™

Comment: closure doesnot know..you should tell them when to execute it...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift, return value from asynchronous block](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26995757/swift-return-value-from-asynchronous-block)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To understand closures and how they work one must understand that they are simply variables as `Int` or `String`, but they also have return value, most commonly `Void`. In a nutshell they allow you to wrap a block of code into single variable you can call later in the code.

Let's take a look at a simple closure definition:

```
let simpleClosure: (Int -> Void) = {
     intValue in   
     print("Number is \(intValue)")
}
```

You can see that closure is instance like any `Int` or `String`, but with return type, in this case `Void` or `()`.

All closures are defined in `{ }` braces with input values defined first (in this case it is `intValue`). This `intValue` will come from the `Int` parameter in closure definition. Let's see how we can call this closure.

```
simpleClosure(5)
```

This will print following:

```
// Number is 5
```

What happened here is that number `5` is passed to the `Int` closure parameter and you get it through `intValue` variable as described above. Since we are returning `Void` we don't need to write `return` statement and the closure finished execution.

Now to the question, closure doesn't know automatically when it is executed, rather it is called when some task is executed. Asynchronous network calls is pretty much the same. You perform network task synchronously (on low level TCP protocol) and notify the programmer when the task is finished via closure. This is the example of how it may be implemented:

```
func networkRequest(url: String, closure: (NSData?,ErrorType?) -> ()) {
    runRequest(url)
    let response = getServerResponse()
    closure(response.data, response.error)
}
```

To summarize up, it's up to programmer to decide when closure is executed and that operation does not happen automatically.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. In the question I asked above I added code. How would that callback know when to be executed? I am very new to this so thanks for the help!

Comment: The moment you call `callback(hingeImages: hingeImageArray, error: nil)` the closure is executed.

Comment: But what if all the items I am expecting back are not returned by the time you call this closure? Since its a asynchronous request? What happens with the rest of the expected items? Check EDIT 2 above in code

Comment: Then you need to call the closure inside the network request closure so that they appear nested. You can call closure inside any other closure multiple times, thus achieving the result you want.

Comment: Can you show me an example in code? I am really trying to learn this!!

Comment: Sure, here it is: [gist](https://gist.github.com/SaidSikira/bb204d832f1acffd0200dd7525749f0c)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109722/discussion-between-stevesmith-and-said-sikira).